# What is the syntax to using await and async in asynchronous functions using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to create a basic API in nodejs to perform CRUD actions on a database.
I do not understand why the result is undefined

```
exports.getPlaylist = async function (req, res) {
  console.log('Recieved getPlaylist request');
  result = await connection.executeQuery('SELECT * from Users');
  res.status(200).send(result);
  console.log(result); // Logs undefined
};
```

This is the function that gets called and gets the data from the database:

```
async executeQuery(query) {
    connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error executing query: ' + err);
        }

        console.log(result); // logs correct data
        return result;

    });
}
```

Comment: executeQuery does not return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` is not a promise base function, you cannot use `await` on a callback function.

change the `execute` function to `promise` base

Example:

```
 executeQuery(query) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
          console.log('Error executing query: ' + err);
          reject('Error executing query: ' + err);
      }

      console.log(result); // logs correct data
      resolve(result);

  });
  });

}
```

Add try catch in your calling function

```
exports.getPlaylist = async function (req, res) {
  console.log('Recieved getPlaylist request');
  try{
    result = await connection.executeQuery('SELECT * from Users');
    res.status(200).send(result);
    console.log(result); // Logs undefined
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

};
```

Comment: You don't need to add `async` to `executeQuery` function. You're already returning a `Promise`. `async` just wrap the function into a `Promise`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to "promisify" your callback. (see `require('utils').promisify` ) for  a shorthand for applying to functions that follow node.js callback style (`function(err,result){}`).

```
executeQuery(query) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error executing query: ' + err);
                rej(err)
            } else {
                console.log(result); // logs correct data
                res(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now inside an `async` function you can `await executeQuery(query)`